# Замена текста в Java

Tags: java

Изучаю Java  не так давно, и хочу создать простенькую  библиотеку замены.
И не могу точно  понять какой метод использовать при этом.
Мне нужно что бы  цифры, заменяло на  текст, при работе цикла . А колличество  значений определялось  длинной массива, или то что заменяло бы его.
Прилагаю код, код не  обрабатывает замену просто выводит цифры.

```
   int i1=0;
  String [] numbers = new String[3];
    numbers[0]="1";
    numbers[1]="2";
    numbers[2]="3";

  String[] symbols = new String[3];
   symbols[0]="одИн";
   symbols[1]="двА";
   symbols[2]="Тры";
   int LengthArray = numbers.length;
  do
   {
    i1=i1+1;   // i1++
     //System.out.println(i1);
     String i01 = Integer.toString(i1);
     System.out.println(i01.replaceAll(numbers[i1],symbols[i1]));   
    }        
    while(i1<=LengthArray - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял, что именно Вы хотите сделать, но если правильно уловил мысль, то вам лучше использовать ассоциативный контейнер map.

```
Map<Character, String> replaces = new HashMap<>();
replaces.put('1', "один");
replaces.put('2', "два");

/* ... */

for (Character c : input)
    System.out.println(replaces.get(c));
```

Comment: Ох, спасибо надо попробовать.   Повторюсь конечно,  мне нужно что бы  цифры заменяло на  текст, при работе цикла . Колличество  значений определялось  длинной массива, или то что заменяло бы его.

Answer (score 1):

В целом, ответ от @saltukkos полностью удовлетворяет Вашему условию. В качестве входных данных приходит Map, где явно обозначается соответствие цифры символу:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Мапа для замены значений
    Map<String, String> replaces = new HashMap<>();
    replaces.put("1", "один");
    replaces.put("2", "два");
    replaces.put("3", "три");
    //Исходная строка
    String s = "1,2,3,4,5 ааа рпрмим";

    //Переводим исходную строку в массив символов
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    //Буфер числа. Сюда будем добавлять поочередно цифры, пока не кончится число
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    //Проходим по массиву исходных символов
    for (int i=0; i<chars.length;i++) {
        //Если символ = цифра
        if (Character.isDigit(chars[i])) {
            //Добавляем цифру в буфер
            buffer.append(chars[i]);
        } else {
            //Если в буфере есть другие цифры
            if (buffer.length()>0) {
                //Пытаемся получить из мапы значение, соотв. нашему числу
                //Если такое число есть, мапа передаст в переменную его словестный аналог, иначе null
                String word = replaces.get(buffer.toString());
                //Если мы что-то получили из мапы
                if (word != null)
                    //Заменяем в исходной строке число из буфера на слово
                    s = s.replaceAll(buffer.toString(), word);
                //Заново инициализируем буфер
                buffer = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HashMap хранит данные в формате Ключ-значение. При этом, поиск по ключу занимает константное, достаточно короткое время (есть правда худший случай, когда за линейное, но здесь это не так важно).